# "Manage" option vanished on portal for Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I had a database which I deleted and it used to have a "Manage" option which would open the online sql management portal.

I created a new database, now I don't have the "Manage" option anymore.

I cannot connect when I try to go to the same URL with my new server name.

I'm also having issues connecting to this new database using Entity Framework. The error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The manage button is no longer available for V12 SQL databases on Azure. Official response from support engineer at Azure:

> The Manage button is not available on Azure SQL Database V12. It is
>   only compatible with the previous version of azure SQL Database, V2
>   (or V11). With the new database that you created, you may use either
>   Visual Studio, or SQL Server Management Studio to manage them.